# D3 data() does not cause anything to change

Tags: d3.js

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70h3a9x2/) produces a table and assigns to a variable a selector for the trs on that table.  It appends a new tr on enter().

```
var trs = table.append('tbody')
    .selectAll('tr');
trs.data([]).enter()
    .append('tr')
```

It then sets a timeout and adds data to the table.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  trs.data(movies);
}, 1000);
```

However, nothing changes after the timeout is complete.  In fact, trs.__data__ is undefined.

Why doesn't calling trs.data() result in any changes?

Answer (score 0):

I already know the answer to this question: I have to recreate the selector and the .enter().append() call inside the setTimeout callback.